# How to return rows that do not exist in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table A like that:

```
CompanyID | SectionID | Service Name
------------------------------------
    1     |     1     |   AAAAAAA
    1     |     2     |   BBBBBBB 
    2     |     1     |   CCCCCCC
```

and a table b like this:

```
  InspectionID | CompanyID | SectionID
  -------------------------------------    
        1      |    1      |     2
        2      |    2      |     1
```

I want a SQL command that returns every Service Name (from table a) that does not have a related inspection (table B joining by `CompanyID` and `SectionID`)

Like that:

```
Service Name
------------ 
 BBBBBBB
```

Thanks!

Comment: If that is the case your output should be AAAAAAA. Am i right? If i am wrong pls tell me how.

Comment: look for examples of "WHERE NOT EXISTS" on the internet.

Comment: Because of the SectionID @Kritner

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
SELECT distinct [Service name]
FROM tableA a
left join tableb b on a.companyId = b.companyId
    and a.sectionId = b.sectionId
where b.companyId is null
```

or

```
select distinct [Service name]
from tablea a
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tableb b
    where a.companyId = b.companyId
        and a.sectionId = b.sectionId
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.[Service name]
from a
left join b on a.companyID = b.companyID
           and a.sectionID = b.sectionID
group by a.[Service name]
having sum(case when b.InspectionID is not null then 1 end) = 0
```